# openCV c++ x64 vc14 binary?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am playing with openCV in C++. I happened to install VS2015 on my PC so I guess I will need a vc14 build of it. However, the official package does not come with it but vc10-vc12.

I first used the vc12 files as they passed project building, but some errors pop out when the deconstructor comes in (namely, deconstructing vector< KeyPoints >). Then I built the binary myself. The building went through, but when the binary is put in the project, the compiler keeps producing error of "unresolved external symbol". I wonder if I can download the x64 vc14 build somewhere so I can skip the pain?

Comment: Correcting _unresolved external symbol_ should take less than waiting for OpenCV to provide prebuilt vc14 binaries. Show library directory and additional libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project should be built with the same platform toolset with the OpenCV libraries. You can set

```
Configuration Properties -> General : Platform Toolset
```

property to v12 for your project so that you can use v12 libraries of OpenCV even with Visual Studio 2015.

I have also recently downloaded OpenCV 3.0 and in the directory :

`opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib`

You can find v12 prebuilt static libraries. Unless you neeed to use the most recent updates in the c++ standard, that will suffice to you.

Comment: That's not going to produce a vc14 binary, is it? And I think you need VS2012 installed to have the v11 toolset.

Comment: All right, I later find out that it probably was openCV's bug. I reserved a large space for the vector<KeyPoints> and the error never came out. As with VS2015, I used the vc12 build directly with no special treatment, and my VS project compiler is v140.

Comment: VS2015 doesn't have v12 toolset. Probably, you had VS2013 (previous) installed and, because of it, your environment recognized this toolset.